# how to set dummy variable as path in multipleinput in map-reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hbase

I have passed hbase table data using `scan` to the mapper. Is there any way to set Dummy path or variable as path argument in `MultipleInput()`

```
List<Scan> scans = new ArrayList();
scans.add(data);

TableMapReduceUtils.initTableMapperJob(scans, Mapper.class, 
  ImmutalbeWriteable.class, ImmutalbeWriteable.class, job);

MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path("DUMMY"), 
  SequenceFileInputFormat.class, Mapper.class)
```

> I'm getting error: This path doesn't exits, while passing `DUMMY`
> variable in path like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path("DUMMY"), 
  MultiTableInputFormat.class, Mapper.class)
```